# Comparing each components in two matrix with for statement

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am comparing each component in two matrices and pairs of dimnames.

Below is example matrices

```
mat1 
|    |  D1|  D2| D3| D4|
| D1 |  NA|   1|  2|  2|
| D2 |  NA|  NA|  3|  8|
| D3 |  NA|  NA| NA|  8|
| D4 |  NA|  NA| NA| NA|

mat2 
|    |  D1|  D2| D3| D4|
| D1 |  NA|   2|  4|  1|
| D2 |  NA|  NA| 13| 10|
| D3 |  NA|  NA| NA|  5|
| D4 |  NA|  NA| NA| NA|
```

I tried to compare it using "for" and get pairs with code below.

```
check = c()
for(i in 2:4){
    for(j in 1:i-1){
        if(mat1[j,i] < mat2[j,i])
        {check= append(check, 100*j + i}
        }
}
```

But comes out with this error messages

```
Error in if (mat1[j, i] < mat2[j, i]) { : 
  argument is of length zero)
```

I can understand that this error comes from here,

```
> mat1[j, i] < mat2[j, i]
logical(0)
```

But don't know how to solve it.

Or any other approaches to solve this problem would be super helpful thank you!

Comparing each components in two matrix with for statement